# Error compiling python

Tags: python

Whenever I try to execute this code:

```
name = input("What's your name?")
print("Hello World", name)
```

By running the command `python myprogram.py` on the command line, it gives me this error:

```
What's your name?John
     Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "HelloWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
             name = input("What's your name?")
         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

It asks me the name but as soon as I type it and press enter it crashes, what does the error mean?
Thanks.

Comment: The error means that you're using Python 2.x.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I know, this is like a new record from what I've seen

Comment: This seems to be already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179875/command-line-input-in-python

Comment: @Greg Yup, it's already been answered 100 times over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2 you should use `raw_input` instead of `input` in this case.

Comment: Ok that solved the problem, however I checked with dnf (I'm using Fedora 25) and I do have Python 3.5.4 so I should be able to use `input` instead of `raw_input`

Comment: @BeppeChiari Having Python 3.x doesn't mean you're using Python 3.x.

Comment: can you check you actual version using `python --version` ?

Comment: Did it, it says Python 2.7.13, how do I change that? I'm using Fedora 25

Comment: @BeppeChiari Please do your own research.

Comment: This is another question ;)

Comment: @JulienSalinas Another duplicate question :)

Comment: Try running using "python3 myprogram.py"

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you @IU5er

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python 2 when you enter just (John) it interprets that as variable. You will either need to enter ("John"), forcing it to see a string, or use name = raw_input() in the first line.