# Get async input from console in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, user-input

I'm doing python program which when working can get input from terminal.

For, example while running some process he can be async controlled from terminal commands and he not stops for user input.

How to do that in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command line input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179875/command-line-input-in-python)

Comment: @BaruchG. I need to program doesn't stop for user input

Comment: Have you looked into processes or threads?

Comment: @adamkgray I tried to do that with threading

Comment: @Dmitry Why did threading not work?

Comment: Can you post example code so we can replicate?

Comment: @adamkgray [example] (https://pastebin.com/AZk9w8xb). This code works, but when the program displays something on the screen, user input is reset and the output is not displayed in a specific way.